# Undefined local variable or method 'user_response'

Tags: ruby, undefined

I've read my code up and down for about 30 mins now. I can't for the life of me see where user_response is undefined. I'm very new to coding so I don't know how much of the code would be appropriate to paste in here. I figure that launch and get_action are essential but the rest couldn't hurt?

```
error => rb:32:in `launch!': undefined local variable or method `user_response' for
<Guide:0x007fb019984718> (NameError)

class Guide

    class Config
        @@actions = ['list', 'find', 'add', 'quit']
        def self.actions
        @@actions
        end
    end

    def initialize(path=nil)
        # locate the restaurant text file at path
        Restaurant.filepath = path
        if Restaurant.file_usable?
            puts "Found restaurant file."
        # or IF a new text file can't be created, create a new file
        elsif Restaurant.create_file
            puts "Created restaurant file."
        # exit if create fails
        else
            puts "Exiting"
            exit!
        end
    end

    def launch! #! means that it is a strong powerful method!
        introduction
        # action loop
        result = nil
        until result == :quit
            action = get_action 
            result = do_action(user_response)
        end
        conclusion
    end

    def get_action
        action = nil
        # Keep asking for user input until we get a valid action
        until Guide::Config.actions.include?(action)
        puts "Actions: " + Guide::Config.actions.join(", ") if action
        print "> "
        user_response = gets.chomp
        action = user_response.downcase.strip
        end
        return action
    end

    def do_action(action)
        case action 
        when 'list'
            puts "Listing..."
        when 'find'
            puts "Finding..."
        when 'add'
            puts "Adding..."
        when 'quit'
            return :quit
        else puts " I don't understand that command."
        end

    end  

    def introduction
        puts "<<< Welcome to the Food Finder >>>"
        puts "This is an interactive guide to help you find the food you crave."
    end

    def conclusion
        puts "<<< Goodbye and Bon Appetit! >>>>"
    end

end
```

Comment: in `lauch!` method, i see this line `result = do_action(user_response)`, but `user_response` has not defined anywhere before,

Comment: where you declare `user_response`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do this :

```
def launch! #! means that it is a strong powerful method!
    introduction
    # action loop
    result = nil
    until result == :quit
        result = do_action(get_action)
    end
    conclusion
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The only time you define a variable called `user_response` is in your `get_action` method.
The way you define it there makes it a local variable and it will not be accessible from anywhere but inside the `get_action` method.